# Matlab: how to compute adjusted R squared for AR model

Tags: matlab, arima

I've got an econometrics problem in which I have to compute in Matlab an AR(15) time series. After asking me to compute BIC and AIC values, the professor requests also the adjusted R squared statistics, but in this case I have no clue on how to compute it.

I've already implemented the AR model through the command 'arima('ARlags', 1:15)' and using the command 'estimate' I obtained the values of the constant, the 15 AR coefficients and the variance.
I know how to compute the adjusted R squared: I have to calculate the sum of squares of residuals and total sum of squares and divide each by the degrees of freedom. However in this case I do not have, like in any statistics problem, the estimated values of my response, so I do not know how to calculate the residual sum of squares and then the adjusted R squared.
Thanks in advance for any help

`parcorr(zero_rate)
 AR1=arima('ARlags', 1:15);
[est_AR1,EstParamCov1,logL1]=estimate(AR1,zero_rate);
[AIC1, BIC1]=aicbic(logL1,17,35);`

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your code showing what you have tried.

Comment: I have a curve about the zero rates in Belgium with different time maturities.
I moved on like this:
I checked the order p using the autocorrelogram (the last lag out of the CI region is 15), and then I used arima and estimate to create my AR(15) model
`parcorr(zero_rate);
 AR1=arima('ARlags', 1:15);
[est_AR1,EstParamCov1,logL1]=estimate(AR1,zero_rate);
[AIC1, BIC1]=aicbic(logL1,17,35);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the [arima class](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/arima.infer.html) , you can use the infer method to get the residuals and then do a dot product to get the sum of squares

```
E = infer(Mdl,Y)
Ssquares = dot(E,E)
```

To get the total sum of squares, you can do

```
Stotal = dot(Y-mean(Y),Y-mean(Y))
```

Then the R squared is just

```
Rsq = 1- Ssquares/Stotal
```

The adjusted R squared

```
Rsqadj - 1- (1-Rsq)*(n-1)/(n-p-1) (which is = 1-Ssquares/Stotal*(n-1)/(n-p-1))
```

Where n is your population size, and p is the number of non-intercept coefficients (in your case, i think this is 15).

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know the command infer! But what about the adjusted R squared?

Comment: Once you have R squared, the adjusted R squared can also be computed. I'll include the formula in my answer.